# Angular2 dynamically generating Reactive forms

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a concept question and would like some advice.
So I have a component, myFormArray, which is a reactive form. It takes in an input array, and creates a number of FormControls accordingly.

```
@Component({
selector: 'myFormArray',
templateUrl: 'formarray.component.html'
})

export class FormArrayComponent{ 
@Input() classFields: any[];  

userForm = new FormGroup();

ngOnInit(){
// psuedocode here, but I know how to implement
    for (# of entries in classFields)
    userForm.FormArray.push(new FormControl());
}
```

Now, in my parent html, I will be dynamically generating multiple myFormArrays. If that is confusing, assume I'm doing this:

```
     <myFormArray [classFields] = "element.subArray"/>
     <myFormArray [classFields] = "element2.subArray"/>
     <button (click) = "save()"> //I don't know how to implement this!
```

And at the very end of the page, I want a save button, that can somehow grab all the values the user inputs in to all the forms, and pushes all this data to an array in a Service component. I'm not sure exactly how to do this part. Note that I don't want individual submit buttons for each dynamically generated form component.

How would I implement this functionality? Thanks!

Comment: In https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form you have a full example of dinamic froms

Comment: I've read that already, but either I'm misreading or it doesn't answer my question. It merely changes the form properties based on different inputs, which I've already done in myFormArray.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically creating input forms in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026895/dynamically-creating-input-forms-in-angular2)

Comment: this link also helped a lot. It is a way to refer to multiple instances of a component and then you can extract the information from your formControl/array/whatever:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your start is good, but you have to write your source code differently.

Instead of this example `app.components.ts` is main component and `my-array.component.ts` is child component.

**Our test data**

```
classFields1: any[] = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password'];
classFields2: any[] = ['country', 'city', 'street', 'zipcode'];
```

**Step 1. Use FormBuilder for form creation (app.component.ts)**

You must import `FormBuilder` and `FormGroup` from `@angular/forms` like this:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

and then define in constructor:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
```

**Step 2. Define new empty FormGrooup**

Now you can define new empty FormGroup in `ngOnInit` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
}
```

**Step 3. Create FormControls dynamically (app.component.ts)**

Now you can start with dynamically creation of your `FormControls` by iteration of `classFields`. For this I would recommend to create own function. This function gets two parameter: `arrayName` and `classFields`. With `arrayName` we can set custom name of our `FormArray`-control. `classFields`-Array we will use for iteration. We create constant variable for empty `FormArray`, which we called `arrayControls`. After this we iterate over `classFields` and create for each element `FormControl`, which we called `control`, and push this `control` into `arrayControls`. At the end of this function we add our `arrayControls` to our Form with custom name by using `arrayName`. Here is an example:

```
createDynamicArrayControls(arrayName: string, classFields: any[]) {
    const defaultValue = null;
    const arrayControls: FormArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    classFields.forEach(classField => {
      const control = this.formBuilder.control(defaultValue, Validators.required);
      arrayControls.push(control);
    })
    this.myForm.addControl(arrayName, arrayControls);
  }
```

Import `FormControl` and `FormArray` from `@angular/forms`. Your import line should be like this:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

Now call `createDynamicFormControls`-Function in `ngOnInit`.

**Step 4. HTML Template for this dynamic Form (app.component.html)**

For this example I create following template:

```
<h1>My Form</h1>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formGroupName="test1">
    <app-my-array [classFields]="classFields1" [arrayFormName]="myForm.controls.test1"></app-my-array>
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="test2">
    <app-my-array [classFields]="classFields2" [arrayFormName]="myForm.controls.test2"></app-my-array>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="saveForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here we have new div element with `formGroupName`. This group name is our `arrayName` in our form. We give our form arrays via `@Input` to `my-array.component`.

**Step 5. MyArrayComponent**

Now  this component is very simnple:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-array',
  templateUrl: './my-array.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-array.component.css']
})
export class MyArrayComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() classFields: any[];
  @Input() arrayFormName: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Here we have only two `@Input` varibales. (I know, this variable can have a better names :-) ).

**Step 6. HTML for MyArrayComponent**

```
<div [formGroup]="arrayFormName">
  <div *ngFor="let class of arrayFormName.controls; let index = index;">
    <label [for]="classFields[index]">{{ classFields[index] }}</label>
    <input type="text" [id]="classFields[index]" [formControlName]="index" />
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

And here is working example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wawsja

If you have some question ask me in comments or read the Angular documentation abour Reactive Forms [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! But my question was really this:

In my parent.html, I will be making two instances of MyArrayComponent. Is it possible to then have a save button, that will be able to see both of those instances and the values within?

Comment: Edited question to reflect my comment

Comment: @ellusion I will update my answer a little bit later today

Comment: @ellusion I have updated my example for you qeustion https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wawsja